# localhost:3000 front end not loading on NextJS app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

New React developer here. I have an eCommerce application I've been working through (Strapi backend, Next frontend), I'm having a lot of trouble when it comes to loading the front end on localhost.

I run the backend with npm start on localhost:1337, loads fine. I then try to run the front end with npm run dev, however, localhost:3000 doesn't load. Previously, my localhost:3000 was in use by a Razer server which I would terminate, however, this fix doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've tried updating my package.json file as below to load the frontend on a different port.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "set PORT=3008 && next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

I've also tried netstat as below in cmd which didn't return any results

```
netstat -a -o | find "3008"
```

I've checked Porthog to see if port 3000/3008 are in use after starting my front end, and each time the below is shown.

```
PORT      PID       PROCESS
--------------------------------------------------
3000      -         -
```

As a last resort, I have also restarted my PC multiple times.

Feeling a bit defeated so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you run `npm run dev` (or your package manager's equivalent), what does it say in the console?

Comment: @Axiumin_

```
PS D:\Development\React\Styled\frontend> npm run dev      

> frontend@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from D:\Development\React\Styled\frontend\.env.local
```
https://gyazo.com/9303f2e6fbc63e9073810110a3aa5668
Followed by some ReferenceErrors for my Stripe integration I need to fix, however, I don't believe this should be an issue as I have accessed the front end before when working on Stripe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you provided is actually a compile-time error, which means it'll completely stop the development server. You'll have to fix the error before being able to run the dev server.

A good way to check whether your dev server has stopped is whether you see the terminal prompt (in your case, `PS (path)>`).  If it's running, it won't have that, and your last log should be something along the lines of `compiled / successfully`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I uninstalled Stripe and removed all my code relating to it and it is now working. Can't believe the answer was right in front of me the whole time.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me

1. Delete the .next folder and try npm run dev command **OR**
2. Move the project to another folder location **OR**
3. Take back up of the code and delete the project and then run the same project again
4. You can try all of the above also

Comment: Deleting the .next folder and running npm run dev worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As there aren't many solutions available on the internet, some of them involve changing the node version. But, I already had a few projects running on my machine that required a specific version of node, so I opted against using this method.

I therefore installed nextjs using WSL on Windows and used wsl to access the nextjs project in vscode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nextjs-on-wsl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkIA.png)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the reason the dev server stopped working was that something in my cookies was causing errors. All I had to do was delete all the cookies, and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Can you check if you installed the packages you are referencing in your app? for me, it was because I set up TailwindCSS configuration without actually installing TailwindCSS

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone still have this issue, fixed it by reinstalling nodejs on my local machine. You can try updating your existing installation and see if that works. In my own case I reinstalled to the lastest version.